# Shut down windows azure role instance via SDK

Tags: azure, azure-sdk-.net

I want to shut down a specified cloud service role instance.

Microsoft provides API [VirtualMachineOperations.beginShutdown(serviceName, deploymentName, virtualMachineName, parameters, callback)](http://dl.windowsazure.com/nodedocs/VirtualMachineOperations-VirtualMachineOperations.html).

I know the serviceName and deploymentName, and the virtualMachineName is specified in ServiceConfiguration.Cloud.cscfg vmName attribute(which is hostName property of roleInstance).

But it reports 'Role instance name is not valid.'.

Any suggestions?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That API manages IaaS Virtual Machines, but it sounds like you are interested in a PaaS instance.  To delete a specific PaaS instance (ie. WebRole1_IN_2) you can use Delete Role Instances API - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn469418.aspx.